# Differentiating Web Api Controllers By Namespace When Using Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using attribute routing for Web Api. What I am trying to accomplish is to write a controller selector so that controller classes sharing the same name but that reside under different namespaces will be reached using their different attribute routes (as Web Api does not allow this by default).

I have searched the web for examples and found the following:

https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebAPIContrib/pull/111/files
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/NamespaceControllerSelector/NamespaceHttpControllerSelector.cs

But as far as I can understand, they seem to be modifications for the default {controller}/{action}/{id} style convention based routing. Because they use `routeData.Values.TryGetValue(ControllerKey, out controllerName)` to get the controller name  from the request route data in the controller selector. But since I am using attributes, I guess I cannot use this.

Is there a sample or a guide that shows how to accomplish this using attribute routing?

EDIT1:
Here is a simple example of the scenario I described as requested in a comment:

```
namespace NS1
{

    public class Class1 : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("dosomething1")]
        public object DoSomething()
        {
        }
    }
}

namespace NS2
{

    public class Class1 : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("dosomething2")]
        public object DoSomething()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain "...sharing the same name but that reside under different namespaces will be reached using their different attribute routes" ? not quite understandable.

Comment: You can simply use `RoutePrefix` to differentiate controller like `[RoutePrefix("api/NS1")]`